# How do you expose sites you distribute to netlify to Google?

Tags: netlify

I just want the main page to be exposed but do I need server side rendering? How can a site deployed in netlify be exposed to search engines like Google?

Comment: This is a great question for https://community.netlify.com/

Comment: Netlify also had a community. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Netlify website is public and you would like to speed up the Google Search Index process, and improve your ranking -  here are some helpful links by Google:

- [Get on Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6259634?hl=en)
- [Improve your performance on Google Search](https://search.google.com/search-console/about?hl=en&utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=wmx-welcome)

This is not really a Netlify specific question, but a website question in general question.